# Blender not autosaving .blend files that are located in D: drive

Tags: saving, settings

Blender has been autosaving all my files normally but for some reason, once I started storing my projects outside my SSD, blender no longer autosaves them. It resumes to autosaving them again once I move the blend file back to SSD.

Any idea why blender can't auto save files from Hard drive?

Some background info: Just got a new PC, this was not a problem in my old laptop setup, I could easily find the autosaves before. So I was thinking did I setup my PC wrong. Is Blender unable to locate my hard disk?

Comment: Can be an access issue... Check if you can write files in that directory from Blender

Comment: By writing files, im assuming you mean if i can save stuff from blender on the drive or the temp folder. I can save and open blender files from blender in those locations, so blender definitley sees them, its just refusing to auto save. I might try a fresh reinstall, maybe some plugins are causing issues?